# Pandas: Rounding a joined dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use df.round(), but my columns refuse to round. I'm wondering whether it may be because I have a series of joins just prior to rounding. If so, I'm not sure how to fix it.

Sample

```
...

df_2 = pd.merge(df_0, df_1, how='left', on=["Location", "Date"])
del [df_0]
del [df_1]

df_2.round({'Column1':0, 'Column2':0, 'Column3':0, 'Column4':0, 'Column5':0})
```

It' seems that no matter what I try with this setup, my result always includes far too many decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `applymap()` method:

```
df_2=df_2.applymap('{:.2f}'.format).astype(float)
```

**OR**

```
df_2=df_2.applymap(lambda x: f"{x:.2f}").astype(float)
```

**Note:**

```
#here in `.2f}` change the precision value according to your need(currently it is 2)
           ^
      #precision value
```

Comment: Yeah just tried and fixed it...thanks @tdy for noticing **:)**